# Uploading Excel file created using OfficeJS add-in is not producing the expected XML structure

Tags: excel, office-js, export-to-excel, exceljs

I am working on an Office.js add-in where I need to generate an Excel file and upload it to a server. I am able to create the file using the ExcelJS library, but when I upload it, the resulting file does not have the expected XML structure.

Here is the code I am using to generate the Excel file:

```
const convertDataToXLSX = async (preparedData: any) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(preparedData);
    const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
    const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet(sheetData.name);
    worksheet.addRows(data);
    const dateColumns: any = [];
    data.forEach((row: any) => {
      row.forEach((value: any, colIndex: any) => {
        if (value instanceof Date) {
          dateColumns.push(colIndex + 1);
        }
      });
    });
    // Apply date formatting to the cells containing date values
    dateColumns.forEach((colIndex: any) => {
      worksheet.getColumn(colIndex).numFmt = "yyyy-mm-dd";
    });
    const buffer = await workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer();
    const blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" });
    const fileName = "workbook.xlsx";
    const file = new File([blob], fileName, { type: blob.type });
    return file;
  };
```

I am unsure why the resulting Excel file is not being created with the expected XML structure. I have verified that the data and formatting operations are correct, and I am using the correct file type and MIME type.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to properly generate and upload an Excel file with the desired XML structure using Office.js add-in. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you expand `expected XML structure` and `desired XML structure`? What is the issue and what is the expected result?